# I would like to change my account handle

Tags: support, user-accounts, display-names

Is it possible to change my account handle, username?

How do I do this if yes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current and enter a new Display name.
- Only one display name change is allowed every 30 days

NB: I have used `current` in the above URL. Clicking this will therefore work for anyone logged in. But if you wanted, you could just enter your id instead of `current`. But, this link is just the link to the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab shown when you click on your own user name.

[image]

Comment: I've edited the answer to user `current` - hope you don't mind! (rollback if you want) :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ - Thanks. I din't know that existed.

Comment: I only found out yesterday! :)